# Is there any where to submit feature requests for Gmail (or other Google apps)?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

For example, filters are particularly under-featured at the moment.

It'd be great if there was an avenue for people to whine about the things they wanted added, in the hope that Google will decide to add the missing stuff.

Is there an interface for this anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest a feature for:

- [Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)
- [Earth](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CC0QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fearth.google.com%2Fsupport%2Fbin%2Frequest.py%3Fcontact_type%3Dsuggestion&ei=clo2TL39A561nAepvrGMBA&usg=AFQjCNFnjDpId3JsELPV8IJUA7DwRJfUtQ)
- [Finance](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CDsQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsupport%2Ffinance%2Fbin%2Fstatic.py%3Fpage%3Dsuggestions.cs&ei=clo2TL39A561nAepvrGMBA&usg=AFQjCNHUj3xM_GF2rOmpbmZOEjtNi9O9Gg)
- [Gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)
- [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)
- [Maps](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)
- [Sites](http://www.google.com/support/sites/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs)
- [Other products (use a Google search)](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%22suggest+a+feature%22+site%3Agoogle.com)

Comment: Perfect. :) Just hope they do pay attention to these.

Answer (score 0):

Each Google application has a "Suggest a feature" forum.

For a list, see http://www.google.com/search?q=google+%22suggest+a+feature%22 (I won't create a list for each app, but you'll see the options there.)