# Can Gmail forward mail to only one of two places?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'd like to forward incoming Gmail to exactly one of two places, depending on the sender, something like this:

- If the sender is a.com or z.com, forward only to myid@firstforward.com and delete.
- If the sender is anyone else, forward only to myid@secondforward.com and delete.

I've tried doing this with various filter incantations, but with no luck - both filters kick in, and the mail gets forwarded to both places. Is there any way to make it happen?

**EDIT**: I just tried these filters:

- from:(a.com OR z.com) : Skip Inbox, Forward to myid@firstforward.com, Delete it
- from:(-a.com AND -z.com) : Skip Inbox, Forward to myid@secondforward.com, Delete it

This works fine, *except* that all spam is being directed to the second forward as well. (Apparently we're no longer able to negate entire "from" clauses with a single hyphen.)

Comment: 'No luck' - what happens to your email? Are messages being forwarded and not deleted, or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal: Edited for clarity.

Comment: In some ways, Gmail filters are very powerful, but in others rather lacking.

While there's [some evidence that the order of the filters matters](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/in-what-order-are-filters-processed-in-gmail/5113#5113), I don't think that you can rely on it. Certainly there's no action which says "Stop processing more rules" like there is in, say, Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: Perhaps you can add "Star it" to the actions of the first filter, then add `-is:starred` to the search criteria of the second filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Gmail doesn't offer a way to accomplish what I want. Ultimately I just forwarded all Gmail to my web host, and used their [far better and more flexible] filters to send it where I really want it.