# Google Mail Filter for Self Mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am trying to make two rules about my mails coexist.

```
Case 1: "from:@my-domain.net to:my-domain.net"
    - Skip inbox
    - Label "myself"
```

I use the above case to group together every note I send to myself. The problem now is trying to make that rule coexist with one to keep away from my inbox mails I send to other people:

```
Case 2: "from:@my-domain.net AND -to:@my-domain.net"
   - Skip inbox
```

Because I do not want a conflict of rules, I am trying to not overlap both rules. If I send to myself I want a label and not seeing it on my inbox. If I send to some other person, I just want to skip the inbox.

However the rule for "Case 2" does not work, and it is selecting mails for "Case 1"

How can I make "Case 2" exclude mails sent to my own domain?

Comment: But mails you send doesn't appear in your inbox, do they?

Comment: yes, they absolutely do. I thought that was "normal" for Gmail after some questions I read in the past

Comment: each mail is subject to all rules so couldnt you rule 1"from:@my-domain.net > skip inbox" and rule 2 "to:@my-domain.net > label myself" ? see also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/in-what-order-are-filters-processed-in-gmail