# How will this set of filters be executed?

Tags: gmail-filters, spam-prevention

All of the SPAM I receive is from .net domains. Some of the valid email I receive is also from .net domains. I would like to white list the valid domains and delete the rest. What would happen to email from comcast.net under the following set of filters (paraphrased):

if From is "comcast.net" never send to SPAM

if From is ".net" delete forever

Does the order matter?

Comment: Make sure you're using the "Report spam" button to help Google's spam filters get smarter. See also: [In what order are filters processed in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure Gmail never filters as spam mail from a certain contact or domain (also known as whitelisting):

- Click the Show search options downward-pointing triangle in your Gmail's main search field.
- Type the desired email address under From.
- To whitelist an entire domain (all mail from an address ending in "aboutguide.com", for example), type the just the domain name or the domain name preceded by '@'. To whitelist "aboutguide.com", for instance, type "@aboutguide.com" (not including the quotation marks).
- You do not have to create a separate filter for each address. Separate addresses with '|' in the From: field instead. To whitelist both "jenny@example.com" and "jelani@example.com", enter "jenny@example.com|jelani@example.com", for example.
- Follow the Create filter with this search ›› link at the bottom of the search sheet.
- Make sure Never send it to Spam is checked.
- Click Create filter.